# Protect part of text from external formatting

Tags: fonts

I would like to create a macro `\ProtectedBold`
such that

```
foo \textit{\ProtectedBold{bar}}
```

would compile as "foo **bar**" and not "foo ***bar***".

What is the standard way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ProtectedBold[1]{\textup{\textbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
foo \textit{\ProtectedBold{bar}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if I would want to do the reverse and create a `\ProtectedItalic'?

Comment: @DamienL - `\newcommand\ProtectedItalic[1]{\textmd{\textit{#1}}}`. Assuming that a basic serif font which provides "regular", "bold", "italic" and "bold italic" font shapes is in use, `\textmd` is to `\textbf` what `\textup` is to `\textit`.

Comment: @DamienL - Incidentally, I believe that macro names such as `\ProtectedBold` and `\ProtectedItalic` are *not* particularly clear or descriptive. In contrast, `\UprightBold` and `\NonboldItalic` are pretty much self-explanatory.

Comment: I agree with @Mico comment and I may add that using `\Protected...` may give the impression that it is a native latex command instead of just being custom one.

Comment: @hesham - Indeed, given that LaTeX features macros named `\protect`, `\protected`, `\protected@edef`, `\protected@xdef` etc, you're absolutely right in pointing out that user-defined macros whose names start with `\Protected` may unintentionally create a misleading impression as to their status or origin.